# Converting a List of Sobject to Map with a specific field as the key on each of the records

Tags: apex, soql

I have a list of Opportunity contact role records and I want to convert this into a map with the ContactId as the key and the rest of the record as the value.

```
SObject[] sObjs = DynamicSOQL.Soql('OpportunityContactRole', oppConFields, sObjIds);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am stuck with trying to make the contactId the key

Comment: I hardly ever downvote, but it looks like other people do and if you want to avoid this, put some of your code efforts in the question - so they can see you have been trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without actually writing the code for you, these are the steps:

1. Create a map to hold your objects. Your map will need to be of type `Map<Id,List<SObject>>`
2. Loop your list:  `for(SObject obj : sObjs){}`
3. Check if your map contains an id that matches your current one. `yourMap.containsKey(obj.ContactId)`
4. Yes ? `yourMap.put(obj.ContactId,new SObject[]{obj});`
5. No ? `yourMap.get(obj.ContactId).add(obj);`

Comment: Likely correction: Your map will be of type `Map<Id, List<SObject>>`. Unless the field is unique.

Comment: Ah yes, of course, there are multiple for each. I'll amend.